# How to combine different @State arrays in a struct

Tags: swiftui

I build a View with a List of contents out of Core Data. Each line in the list exists of a static text (name), a checkbox (isChecked) and a textfield (comment).

```
@State var isChecked: [Bool]
@State var comment: [String]
var name: [String]
```

The content will be filled in the init(). Is it possible to wrap this three arrays in a structure like this:

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {

    static let shared = DataController()

    struct myLineContent {
            var name: String
            var isChecked: Bool
            var comment: String
        }

    ...

}

struct myView: View {

    @State var myContent: [DataController.shared.myLineContent]

    init(...) {

        // load content
        var content: [DataController.shared.myLineContent] = []
        // example data
        content.append(DataController.shared.myLineContent(name: "Joe", isChecked: true, comment: "a good friend"))
        content.append(DataController.shared.myLineContent(name: "Michael", isChecked: true, comment: "my neighbor"))
        content.append(DataController.shared.myLineContent(name: "Jenny", isChecked: true, comment: "my friend"))
        content.append(DataController.shared.myLineContent(name: "Ed", isChecked: true, comment: "my father"))
        _myContent = State(initialValue: content)
    }

    var body: some View {
         ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? I tried something but without success.

Comment: "I think it is a bit confusing." What is confusing? Can you show the working code that you think would be confusing, so we know what you are trying to do, and explain what's confusing about it?

Comment: Maybe "confusing" is the wrong word. Sorry for that. I am from german. I have got three arrays. Each index of the three arrays points to a person. e.g. index 0 = Justin, index 1 = Michael, and so on. Instead I only want this three arrays combined in a structure like struct or class. I try to correct the post.

Comment: Then I think you just need `[DataController.myLineContent]` instead of `[DataController.shared.myLineContent]`. You don't need `shared`.

Comment: The usual way is rather the opposite: The array of `MyLineContent` is supposed to be located as `@Published` property in `DataController`, and this controller is declared as `@StateObject` (replacing `@State var myContent`) in the view. And how is the code related to Core Data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized, that I have to learn more about State, StateObject, Binding and ObservableObject. I read many pages about this topic and I get step by step more insight to this. On one page I saw a possible solution for my problem. I also added the person Property in the struct definition of MyLineContent. This is a Core Data Entity named "Person". I added this in the Example. It works fine for me. I wanted to add the link here to the page where I found the solution but I don't know where it was.

```
struct MyLineContent: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var person: Person
    var personName: String
    var isChecked: Bool
    var comment: String
}

struct myView: View {

    @State private var myContent: [MyLineContent] = []
    var personList: [Person]

    init(...) {

        var myTempContent: [MyLineContent] = []
        
        personList = loadPersonData() // loads Person data from Core Data (name, street, ...)

        for i in 0..<personList.count {
            myTempContent.append(MyLineContent(person: personList[i], personName: personList[i].name, isChecked: false, comment: ""))
        }
        
        _myContent = State(initialValue: myTempContent)

    }

    struct CheckBoxView: View {
        @Binding var checked: Bool
        
        var body: some View {
            Image(systemName: checked ? "checkmark.square.fill" : "square")
                .foregroundColor(checked ? Color(UIColor.systemBlue) : Color.secondary)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.checked.toggle()
                }
        }
    } 

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($myContent) { mc in
                HStack {
                    CheckBoxView(checked: mc.isChecked)
                    // personName should not be changed. It shows only the name from the "Person".
                    TextField("", text: mc.personName).disabled(true)
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("", text: mc.comment)
                }
            }
        }
        Button("Speichern", action: saveAction)
    }

    func saveAction() {
        ...
    }

}
```